# How do we select values for parameters when using Differential Privacy?

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

I'm aware we can quantify privacy with [ε-differential privacy (ε-DP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy). But when we apply DP, how do we actually select the value for ε ? Are there some rule-of-thumbs? Is it decided case-by-case basis? In general, how do we decide we've enough privacy when using some algorithm that satisfies ε-DP definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 2019 paper [Differential Privacy in Practice: Expose Your Epsilons!](https://journalprivacyconfidentiality.org/index.php/jpc/article/download/689/685/), the authors Dwork, Kohli, Mulligan summarize the state of affairs thusly:

> We found **no clear consensus on how to choose ε**, nor agreement on how to approach this and other key implementation decisions. Given the importance of these details there is a need for shared learning amongst the differential privacy community.

They propose an "Epsilon Registry" where applications of DP can specify their choice of ε. The closest to such a registry that I've been able to find is [this list of real-world uses of DP](https://desfontain.es/privacy/real-world-differential-privacy.html) by Damien Desfontaines, from Jan 2021.

I also found this [very recent blog post from NIST](https://www.nist.gov/blogs/cybersecurity-insights/differential-privacy-future-work-open-challenges) which says *"what, exactly, does ε mean, and how should we set it? Unfortunately, we still don’t have a consensus answer to this question"*, but then goes on to actually give some broad numerical guidance:

> - There is broad consensus that ε values in the low single digits (i.e. 0 < ε < 5) represent a conservative choice, and will provide strong privacy protection
> - Increasing experience with deployed systems suggests that larger ε values (i.e. 5 < ε < 20) also provide robust privacy protection in a variety of settings
> - In some contexts, even higher values of ε (i.e. ε > 20) may still provide meaningful privacy protection, but more experience is needed to understand this setting

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful resources.